# How to get [[boundthis]] from function

Tags: javascript

I need your help.
I have 2 functions:

```
addMoveListeners: function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  // Binging context to function move
  moveListener = MYAPP.move.bind(e.target.parentElement);
  //
  if (e.target.classList.contains('move')){
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveListener, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', MYAPP.removeListener, false);
  }
  resizeListener = MYAPP.resize.bind(e.target.parentElement);
  if (e.target.classList.contains('resize')){
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeListener, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', MYAPP.removeListener, false);
  }
  return false;
},
```

and this:

```
removeListener: function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  //Here I want get element from function
  console.dir(resizeListener);
  // Function stores it in [[BoundThis]]
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizeListener, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', MYAPP.removeListener, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveListener, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', MYAPP.moveListener, false);
},
```

How can I get property [[BoundThis]] from function resizeListener without execution.

Comment: what is BoundThis, you mean this?

Comment: console.dir(function) give me this - [[BoundThis]]: div.note.note2

Comment: @unikorn: the OP has called `Function.prototype.bind` on the handler -- I suspect the OP wants to get the `this` value that has been bound to the function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot. `[[BoundThis]]` is an [internal property of bound function objects](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2). It is not programmatically accessible.

You might be able to view it with inspection of the object via console, but to use it in your program logic you will need to write your own version of `bind` that exposes this value as a property.

Comment: if it is not programmatically accessible, then how is chrome able to access it? is there maybe access to using chrome debugger through an extension? I'm interested in doing this only locally

Comment: @RaduSimionescu Yes, the debugger can access it.

Comment: [bind2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bind2) allows you to access the bound this argument (they call it `context`)

Comment: looks like bind2 only works for functions that where bound with bind2.