# Assert that a function has been bound early

Tags: javascript

### Description

For the purpose of a unit test, I would like to check if a particular function has been bound.

### Example

```
function foo() {}
var bar = foo.bind(context);

assertBound(bar); // --> true
assertBound(foo); // --> false
```

### Question

Is there someway to check that `bar` has been bound that doesn't require mocking the `bind` function?

### Notes

While [How to get [[boundthis]] from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401379/how-to-get-boundthis-from-function) is asking about getting the `[[boundthis]]`, I am wondering about just checking it has been bound.

Comment: In this case you'd need to hijack `bind`, not just create your own `bind` function. On the other hand, OP, specifies that he doesn't want to mock the `bind` function. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I updated the question to make it not a duplicate.

Comment: Was going to vote to reopen, then noticed it had been.  It looks like there might be a `.name` property available in some browsers that are starting to support ES6, where the name of a function returned from `bind` is `"bound "+ originalFunctionName` - won't post it as an answer as I'm unsure if it's defined exactly that way in the spec or not, but may get you started...

Comment: @JamesThorpe This is true, but this can't be the answer since it doesn't display the actual context bound to the function, as required by the question. I have reopened the question, however I doubt that the author will get any reasonable reply.

Comment: Per the above - it's [step 15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind) in ES6, and [is missing from ES 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), so depending on your environment you may or may not be able to use it.

Comment: @VisioN, OP doesn't want to get the bounded context. Just want to know if it's bounded.

Comment: @VisioN I think the OP only wants to know if it _is_ bound, not what it's bound _to_.  If it was what it was bound to, that's what the dupe was for.  If it's just that it _is_ bound, the `name` property in ES6 may be of use.

Comment: Ah, true. The question was updated. Initially he asked: *"Is there someway to check that bar has been bound to `context` that doesn't require mocking the bind function?"*

Comment: @VisioN Yes - that's why I went for the dupe that I did :)

Comment: I updated to remove the context bit so that it wasn't a duplicate. Sorry for the confusion; I should have noted that in my comment or update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `{Function}.name` in ES6

In ES6 all functions are given a static [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

```
function aFunction () {}
console.log(aFunction.name) // => 'aFunction'
```

Unnamed functions like arrow functions have an empty string for their name:

```
var aFunction = function () {}
console.log(aFunction.name) // => ''
```

Both named and unnamed functions when bound to a context using `Function#bind` have their `name` preceded with `'bound '`:

```
// Named function
function aFunction () {}
var boundFunc = aFunction.bind(this)
console.log(boundFunc.name) // => 'bound aFunction'

// Unnamed function
var anotherFunc = function () {} // or `anotherFunc = () => 0`
var anotherBoundFunc = anotherFunc.bind(this)
console.log(anotherBoundFunc.name) // => 'bound '
```

We can use this to see if a function is bound:

```
function assertBound (fn) {
    return typeof fn == 'function' && fn.name.startsWith('bound ');
}
```

*Note:* checking that the word bound has a space after it is important so that we don't catch functions like `function boundFunction () {}`, for example.

______

### `Function#toString` in ES5

A hacky way to know if a user-defined function is bound in ES5 is to cast it to a string using `Function#toString` and looking for the text `'[native code]'`:

```
function assertBound (fn) {
    return typeof fn == 'function' && fn.toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1;
}
```

Comment: Beware of the `[native code]` trick, built-in functions are also stringified this way.

Comment: @MinusFour Absolutely. There isn't a reliable way of checking if a function is bound in ES5. (Rick Hitchcock's answer has a similar problem: many standard built-in functions don't have a `prototype`.)

Comment: I'd go for `.startsWith` instead of `includes`. Nice find!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! What's the reason for your preferring `startsWith`?

Comment: Well it does a different thing and is more efficient? `includes` looks everywhere in the name, but `.bind()` puts `"bound "` only in the beginning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5:

> Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind do not have a
>   prototype property

Here's a possible test:

```
function assertBound(obj) {
  return typeof obj==='function' && 
         typeof obj.prototype==='undefined';
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function foo() {}

function assertBound(obj) {
  return typeof obj==='function' && 
         typeof obj.prototype==='undefined';
}

var context= {},
    bar1 = foo,
    bar2 = foo.bind(context);

console.clear();
console.log(assertBound(foo));      //false
console.log(assertBound(bar1));     //false
console.log(assertBound(bar2));     //true
console.log(assertBound(context));  //false
```

Comment: Of course, any function could have its `.prototype` property set to `undefined` or `delete`d altogether.

Comment: True, but could there be a valid reason to do so?

Comment: Not exactly. But notice that in ES6, class methods and arrow functions won't have `.prototype` properties either, so this approach will break then.