# Javascript [[BoundThis]] value

Tags: javascript, bind

In Javascript (with Chrome Console) i have a button with EventLister

listener = getEventListeners($0)

```
{mousedown: Array(1), mouseenter: Array(1) ...}
```

then i looking into `listener.mousedown[0]`

#### listener f()

[image]
I wanna get value `listerner.mousedown[0].listener[[BoundThis]].ItemListRowView.data.id` (number as you can see) but i don't have idea how to do it

Thanks for help

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this programmatically. The `[[...]]` indicate that this a property that is internal to the engine.

Comment: What i need to do is from this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401379/how-to-get-boundthis-from-function

"You might be able to view it with inspection of the object via console, but to use it in your program logic you will need to write your own version of bind that exposes this value as a property."