# How to extract the this property from a bound function?

Tags: javascript, this

I want to get the value of the this property from a function which is already bound.

```js
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a)
}
const bar = foo.bind({a:1})
bar() // Prints 1
bar.getThis() // should return { a: 1 }
```

In the above example, how do I extract the bound object `{ a: 1 }` from the variable bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by extending the builtin `bind` method like below.

```js
Function.prototype.__bind__ = Function.prototype.bind;

Function.prototype.bind = function(object) {
  var fn = this.__bind__(object);
  fn.getThis = function () {
   return object;
  }
  return fn;
}

function foo(){
  return this.a
}
var bar = foo.bind({a:1})
console.log(bar());
console.log(bar.getThis())
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get that, `[[BoundThis]]` is an [internal property](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) of bound function objects.

You can however see it in the console:

[image]

> The pre-bound this value of a function Object created using the standard built-in Function.prototype.bind method. Only ECMAScript objects created using Function.prototype.bind have a [[BoundThis]] internal property.

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27404645/848250) pointed out, "to use it in your program logic you will need to write your own version of bind that exposes this value as a property".

Nonetheless, if you can add to the `foo()` function, then you could do something along the lines:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);

  return {
    getThis: () => this
  };
}
const bar = foo.bind({ a: 1 });

console.log(bar().getThis()) // { "a": 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

essentially to extract the bound object `{ a: 1 }` you can return or log `this`:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

const bar = foo.bind({ a: 1 });

bar(); // { a: 1 }
```

I hope this help.

Comment: OP wants that from the outside.